# How to get images from email or desktop into iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiwebview

I know this is a very basic question, but something I'm never quite sure of, is how do you get images from say your email, or from your desktop (say a Mac) into your iOS app?

Let's say I develop an app and I want people to be able to put their company's logo into it, how would they do that? I presume they don't have their company logo in their phone, so how would they get it from another source into the app? If they linked to it on the web, wouldn't that just open a `UIWebView` to show it? i.e it wouldn't load the actual `.png` from the web direct to be used by the app or would it?

Comment: The user will open their company website in their mobile Safari, long tap on it and save it into their photo gallery. Then you in your app will request access to the user's photo library, and let the user select the logo and use it in your app.
Also, this is not a programming question. If you've already got your hands dirty, actually writing a related code, and you're stuck at a specific point, then edit your question, add details, show us your code and let us help you better.

Comment: Ah ok, I never knew you could do that, still seems a bit convoluted, but is that common practice for getting images into an App that did not originate from the camera?

Answer (score 2):

So, to avoid long comments, I'm putting my answer here, although this is a very general question.

The common thing with all the apps that want an image input, is that they require the user either take a photo with their phone camera, or grant access to the photo library, so that the user can select an image and upload it to the app. If you have used any of the photo-involved apps these days, you should be familiar with this. Example is *Instagram*, *Facebook*, *Flickr*, etc.

However if you really really want to let the user download it off the internet through your app, then you should embed a web browser in your app, allowing the user type in a URL and save the file in that URL to the documents/downloads folder in your app, and then allow them access those folders to browse and upload stuff. A good example of this kind of app, is "*NuageApp*" which is actually a client for the [Cloud App](http://cl.ly). It's really handy to deal with file sharing the way NuageApp (funky name, huh?!) does, however it's far more complicated to implement that, than the access to the photo library.

Comment: Would saving images from an URL fall foul of any Apples terms and conditions?

Comment: Dunno! Read the guidelines. (: